# DevExpress Node Images not working

Tags: c#, devexpress, treelist

I am using `DevExpress TreeList`. I have read this [article](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_GetSelectImagetopic) and followed the steps.

1. Created `ImageList` and added icons init.
2. TreeList property is set `SelectImageList = ImageList`
3. `TreeList.ImageIndexFieldName = "ImageID"`
4. Following `DataTable` is assigned to `TreeList.DataSource`

Table is given below

```
ID   Name   Parent   ImageID
1    Root     0         0
2    Node1    1         1
3    node2    2         2
4    node3    2         2
```

The Problem is `TreeList` is showing same icon with each node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in this, problem was in the data type.

While adding columns in datatable just mention its type.

```
dt.Columns.Add("Parent", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("ImageID", typeof(decimal));
```